# React native app crashes on startup (android)

Tags: android-studio, react-native

hoping someone would help me out here. I am trying to run an RN app and it gives me the following error:

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xf3fc1000 in tid 21805 (.koktech.sygnal), pid 21805 (.koktech.sygnal)

Stacktrace:

```
2020-11-25 09:32:07.907 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-11-25 09:32:07.907 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86_arm:11/RPB3.200720.005/6705141:user/release-keys'
2020-11-25 09:32:07.908 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2020-11-25 09:32:07.908 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2020-11-25 09:32:07+0545
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: pid: 21805, tid: 21805, name: .koktech.sygnal  >>> com.koktech.sygnal <<<
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10167
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xf3fc1000
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000001  ebx c5b4ce10  ecx d1b2deeb  edx 00000004
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:     edi f3fc1000  esi f3fc1005
2020-11-25 09:32:07.913 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:     ebp ff9d38f8  esp ff9d37b0  eip c5af5ba7
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0002fba7  /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so (p21D53910EA7803D9C28A0DA2CB984240+2695)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 0003004f  /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so (p6D2C699323E0FB9D7881198346D91690+47)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0002ca20  /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so (p242D28305458B1DF2F5D316565C2034F+880)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 000124d4  /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00016e36  /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/lib/x86/libDexHelper_sdk.so (JNI_OnLoad+16214)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0040a468  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*, _jclass*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+3832) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 000052a2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libopenjdkjvm.so (JVM_NativeLoad+402) (BuildId: 28ac75ea3a5406bc0309d555a2fa73cf)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000299d6  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libopenjdk.so (Runtime_nativeLoad+38) (BuildId: 2afc9428a4221bbd5194a685049e887a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 000828da  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+234) (BuildId: b386118502376442aa402e8d28c29e95a6eb8614)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.313 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 0013baf2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 001d0392  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 003866e1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+385) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 0037aa1e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1070) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 007a4d0d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+637) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 00135921  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 000e349e  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad+2)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 007a503e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1454) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 00135921  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 000e39d0  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0+92)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 007a448e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1454) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 001358a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 000e395c  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0+8)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 007a14de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 000e8f24  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.System.loadLibrary+16)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 007a503e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1454) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.314 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 00135921  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 00436802  [anon:dalvik-classes87.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/base.apk!classes87.dex] (com.secneo.sdk.Helper.install+50)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 0036fae2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+370) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 00379bff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+207) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 0037aa00  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1040) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 007a4d0d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+637) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 00135921  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 000a1922  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1Qqsz70DplFZPyQxwqkhow==/com.koktech.sygnal-YJTK-rdgeQJtSZYOgQ56rg==/base.apk] (com.koktech.sygnal.MApplication.attachBaseContext+6)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #34 pc 007a14de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #35 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #36 pc 001bdcb8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Application.attach)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #37 pc 007a14de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #38 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #39 pc 002111e4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication+24)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #40 pc 007a14de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #41 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #42 pc 00215f42  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication+206)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #43 pc 0036fae2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+370) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #44 pc 00379bff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+207) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #45 pc 0037b495  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+2117) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #46 pc 00188d11  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+58609) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #47 pc 00142de2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #48 pc 0019dacc  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.315 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #49 pc 0036fa6e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+254) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #50 pc 00379bff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+207) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #51 pc 0037b495  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+2117) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #52 pc 0018e613  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+81395) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #53 pc 00142de2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #54 pc 0019b050  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #55 pc 0036fa6e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+254) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #56 pc 00379bff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+207) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #57 pc 0037aa00  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1040) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #58 pc 007a4d0d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+637) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #59 pc 00135921  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #60 pc 00197c32  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+1374)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #61 pc 007a14de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #62 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #63 pc 0036f2aa  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x92b000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #64 pc 007a14de  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1806) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #65 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #66 pc 00396aa6  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x92b000) (android.os.Looper.loop+482)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #67 pc 0036fae2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+370) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #68 pc 00379bff  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+207) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #69 pc 0037b495  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+2117) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #70 pc 0018e613  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+81395) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.316 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #71 pc 00142de2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #72 pc 001a1698  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #73 pc 0036fa6e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+254) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #74 pc 00379ae0  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+176) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #75 pc 0078b305  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1061) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #76 pc 0014220d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #77 pc 0013baf2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #78 pc 001d0392  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #79 pc 0062ffe8  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1464) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #80 pc 00588680  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+80) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #81 pc 0008a778  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+168) (BuildId: b386118502376442aa402e8d28c29e95a6eb8614)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #82 pc 0013b922  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #83 pc 001d0381  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+241) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #84 pc 003866e1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+385) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #85 pc 0037aa1e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1070) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #86 pc 007a1197  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+967) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #87 pc 001357a1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #88 pc 0044925e  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x125d000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #89 pc 0036fae2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.12175385690420896393)+370) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #90 pc 00379ae0  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+176) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #91 pc 0078b305  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1061) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #92 pc 0014220d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #93 pc 00893646  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2102) (BuildId: 375b62d9c33d1f72c4ee1fc4e2ab1a8116b1ea03)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #94 pc 0013baf2  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #95 pc 001d0392  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.317 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #96 pc 0062e633  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, char*)+579) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #97 pc 0062eb05  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+85) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #98 pc 004ce62f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+735) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #99 pc 003f8a8e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2846) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #100 pc 003e60b9  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+73) (BuildId: 123e60096a46399e6f56e4eb5c70759a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #101 pc 0008f90e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+62) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #102 pc 00098c8e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+910) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #103 pc 00003804  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1588) (BuildId: c5eedbfb6130af84c3db8e121fb1202e)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.318 21830-21830/? A/DEBUG:       #104 pc 00052263  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so!libc.so (offset 0x46000) (__libc_init+115) (BuildId: 787473e23bc7d49ac38e635c3435c37a)
2020-11-25 09:32:09.644 276-276/? E/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_19
```

Hoping someone would help me understand the reason behind this error.

Comment: Are you using biometric? if yes please test the device compatibility and permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project built fine when building on a real device. Looks like projects running DJI-SDK (Android) don't build on emulators.